# Are cacti more likely to regrow than to appear?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I'm farming cacti in terraria because I like to use them for building:

[image: image description]

Currently, I leave the cacti "stumps" and only cut when they grow 2 tiles high. Is it good strategy? Are the one tile high cacti more likely to grow than spawn anew?

Note that this question is not limited to mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

No, their growth rate isn't affected by their size. I did a few experiments by leaving my pc running for a while and cacti that are tree blocks high spawn a new block just as fast as cacti that are one or two blocks high. Of course there is a maximum height at which they stop growing.

Comment: My question was whether cacti spawn (**on sand**) faster than they grow (spawn on other cacti).

Comment: Ah, my bad, I will preform another test run and edit my answer accordingly. I assume it won't matter that much, but we will see :)

Comment: I wonder if there's any editor that would making the test easier. I wanted to make a test comparing one row of 1 tile cacti to row of sand, but I still don't have a row of completely grown cacti...

Comment: You can try using TEdit http://www.binaryconstruct.com/games/tedit